# is there a note location chart available for 22 hole chromatic harmonica?

Tags: harmonica, chromatic

I am looking for a chart that shows the location of notes, for both draw and blow, as well as the key pressed and unpressed, for a 22 hole chromatic harmonica
[Something like this](http://www.harpinanawhinin.com/IMAGES/C%20Harp%20Note%20Layout.jpg) but for a 22 hole chromatic
I have been searching for hours and I can find ones for diatonic and 12 hole chromatic, but not for a 22 hole one
Could anybody point me in the right direction?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Like you, I've searched for a while for information about 22-hole chromatic harmonicas. The only 22-hole instruments I've found information about ***don't* have different blow and draw notes for each hole.** Instead, instruments such as the **Unica 22-hole chromatic harmonica** have two, rather than four notes, for each hole. (Usually, a chromatic harmonica has 4 notes for each hole: blow and draw notes without using the slide; and blow and draw notes using the slide.) The Unica instrument produces the *same* pitch when a particular hole is blown *or* drawn. This gives two notes per hole; one with and one without using the slide.

[This](http://www.tombo-m.co.jp/eng/slide.html#) website (which I gather you found, too) has charts for a wide range of different types of chromatic harmonicas. One of these is a **22-hole, 44-reed, 44-tone slide harmonica**, which is of the type I mention above. Below is a picture of this instrument (showing the 22 holes) and the fingering chart for this instrument (showing just two notes for each hole - i.e. slide out and slide in):

[image]

As I say, this is the only fingering chart I've managed to find for any 22-hole chromatic harmonica. If your instrument produces the same notes for blow and draw on any particular hole, this might be the correct note location chart. If not, I'm as stumped as you are...

Comment: I had found this page, but that figure doesn't show which ones are blow and which ones are draw

Comment: Aha! This instrument doesn't have blow and draw notes, it only has **"one tone per one hole"**. Does your instrument have blow and draw notes for each hole?

Comment: This question perplexes me, as I have several harmonicas, mostly Hohner. However, they're about 1,000 miles away right now, so when I get home, I'll play them all and report back...  But I feel that most will produce the standard scale, with the scale a semitone out with the button pressed. Watch this space.

Comment: Cheers, Tim. As ever, you are the font of all knowledge!

Comment: I noticed that the company calls this model Unica and has only one note per hole. so does this mean this chart is for this specif manufacturer and their model? If I buy any other cheaper brand harmonica with 22 holes, how likely is it that it's note layout would be different?

Comment: I don't have a harmonica yet so I am doing this to find out whether it would be better to buy a 12 hole or 22 hole one. among the harmonicas I've found, the layout charts for 12 hole ones are more straightforward, but the harmonicas are more expensive. And I couldn't find the layout chart for 22 hole harmonica, but the price is same as the 12 hole one. So I was thinking if the 22 hole one gives me more notes, may be it would be better to but the 22 hole one.

Comment: Ah, well if that is your main question, I would say go for the 12-hole, these are the conventional chromatic harmonicas, with conventional (blow and draw) note location. As far as I can tell, the 22 hole doesn't give you more notes; they are just cheaper because there are no air valves, as each hole only has the same pitch for blow and draw notes.

Comment: Been a long time coming back to this question! Sorry! Come on, it's not 6 yrs yet! My Hohners are 16 hole chromatics, a couple are called '64s', as that's the number of notes available. So four octaves, and what I would call standard tuning (in C) B D B D B D D B, for C D E F G A B C in each octave, and diatonic C# with button depressed.